# Orbeon Forms in different server than app

Tags: orbeon, jboss6.x

I need to update Orbeon Forms but my app is in a JBoss6 and it's impossible to migrate (old dependencies). It's possible to configurate Orbeon in other server (WildFly for example) and invoke the runner since JBoss?

Comment: Hi Lluís, are you using the Java embedding API by any chance, or is your app and Orbeon Forms just 2 completely different apps that users access separately? ‑Alex

Comment: Use with Java embedding API

Comment: Got it Lluís, then I posted an answer below, and you'll let me know if this works for you. ‑Alex

Comment: Hi Lluís, did you get a chance to try the technique described in my answer below? If so, did keeping your app on JBoss 6 and running Orbeon Forms on Tomcat 8.5 or 9 work for you? ‑Alex

Answer (score 0):

Since your app uses the embedding API, Orbeon Forms can run on a different application server, listening on a different port, or even deployed on a different host, and you can keep JBoss 6 for your app. So you could have, maybe even on the same host:

- Your app running on JBoss 6, as you are doing now.
- Orbeon Forms running on Tomcat 8.5 or Tomcat 9, listening on a different port.